# Saving XDocument to file in PCL C#

Tags: c#

I'm working within my PCL library and need to serialise a class and output to a file. I'm very short on space, so don't have the space for PCLStorage.

Currently I'm using this for the serialisation. IFilePath returns a file path from the non-PCL part.

```
    IFilePath FilePath;

    public void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
    {
        if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var xmlDocument = new XDocument();
                using (var writer = xmlDocument.CreateWriter())
                {
                    var serialize = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                    serialize.WriteObject(writer, serializableObject);

                    xmlDocument.Save(ms, SaveOptions.None);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
        }
    }
```

When I try to save, nothing is showing. I have a feeling it's because I'm not outputting the stream to a file, but I'm at a loss as how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to save to a file, an action which is specific for each platform.
PCLStorage is implementing this functionality for each platform and this is what you will have to do also if you can"t use it.

In you case what you have to do is to create the stream (in each platform) in your **non pcl code** and then pass it to your function which will look like this:

```
public void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, Stream fileStream)
{
    if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

    try
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = xmlDocument.CreateWriter())
        {
           var serialize = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
           serialize.WriteObject(writer, serializableObject);
           xmlDocument.Save(fileStream, SaveOptions.None);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception here
    }
}
```

more on pcl [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsplaisted/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you/).

Comment: Thanks - I suspected I would have to go that way though i would have thought that the stream could be sent to a file using StreamWriter/Reader

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your variable ms in `using (var ms = new MemoryStream())` is empty and does not point to any file location of which MemoryStream does not receive a filepath as argument. I propose you use a StreamWriter instead and pass the your FileStream to it. Example

Use your fileName to create a FileStream which inherits from the Stream class then replace the Memory stream with the newly created filestream like this.

```
using(FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
{
    var xmlDocument = new XDocument();
            using (var writer = xmlDocument.CreateWriter())
            {
                var serialize = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                serialize.WriteObject(writer, serializableObject);

                xmlDocument.Save(stream, SaveOptions.None);
            }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is in the pcl, so none of the File* namespace is available.

Comment: the namespace is System.IO